# VPN Sonicwall 190 with MAC OS 10.6.1?

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

Has anyone been able to vpn to a sonicwall 190, using a free or cheap VPN client?

I've tried 
VPN Tracker 6 and it works but don't want to spend $129+

Answer (score 0):

[IPSecuritas](http://www.lobotomo.com/products/IPSecuritas/) is supposed to work. When I used to work at a company that was a SonicWall reseller I never could get it to work. Theoretically the Sonicwall is doing straight IPSec VPN setups, but I was either missing a step or otherwise messing it up.

Comment: Same here, I fill in all the information and it times it self out. I tried all 3 built in Snow Leopard VPN's and none of them work.

Comment: The builtin VPN client won't work as far as I know. You may want to try IPSecuritas and see if you can get it going. I've also been rather impressed with CheckPoint recently as far as it goes with Mac interoperability-in the future you may want to check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Sonicwall and OSX do not get along. Primarily the fault is with OSX changing code and breaking things.

Make sure your sonicwall firmware is up-to-date and try the VPN clients again. If it does not work, the NetExtender may be the best option for you.

Answer (score 0):

A old question, but in the SonicWall you can create a L2TP's configuration to be able to use any vpn client that use that standard. You are not forced to use the default's sonicwall vpn client at all.

[Configuring L2TP Server on SonicOS Enhanced](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/?sol_id=170505258972739)

> The suggested configuration was confirmed to work with Microsoft
>   Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2), Vista Ultimate, and Vista Home
>
> 1) Click on MANAGE , navigate to VPN | Base Settings and enable the
>   WAN GroupVPN policy. The default policy settings are OK to use, but
>   the Shared Secret will
>   be needed for the client policy configuration
>
> Enable the Accept Multiple Proposals for Clients checkbox which allows
>   multiple VPN or L2TP clients using different security policies to
>   connect.   I. Enable the L2TP Server. Click 'Configure' II. L2TP
>   Server Settings  Keep alive time (secs): 60  DNS Server 1: (Use
>   internal or your ISP's DNS)  DNS Server 2: 4.2.2.2 (or use your ISP's
>   DNS)  DNS Server 3: 0.0.0.0 (or use your ISP's DNS)  WINS Server 1:
>   0.0.0.0 (or use your WINS IP)  WINS Server 2: 0.0.0.0 (or use your WINS IP)  III. IP Address Settings  IP address provided by RADIUS/LDAP
>   Server: Disabled  Use the Local L2TP IP Pool: Enabled  Start IP:
>   10.20.0.1 *EXAMPLE*  End IP: 10.20.0.20 *EXAMPLE*  IV. L2TP Users  User Group for L2TP Users: 'Trusted Users'Image
>
> 3) Go to Rules| NAT Policies SonicOS Enhanced will automatically add
>   the following NAT policy.
>
> 4) Go to Rules| Access Rules and select VPN to WAN and Add the
>   following rule.

After you can use procedure as shown there; [Configuring iPod/iPad/iPhone L2TP Client to connect to SonicWall UTM appliances](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/?sol_id=170503425799521)